# Start VScode in projects virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I would like my VScode terminal to be in the correct virtual environment as soon as I open the project folder. At the moment I always have to get out of my conda environment and into the projects environment. I would like a script that runs:

```
conda deactivate
source ~/path/to/activate
```

as soon as I open the project folder in VScode.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Normally speaking, once you choose the interpreter, it will be recorded in workspace cache.

You can manually set your interpreter in **Workspace Settings.json**:

```
"python.pythonPath": "<the full path to your interpreter>"
```

then every time you reopen the project, the environment will automatically redirect to the chosen one and load it.

**[UPDATE]**

Turn to the directory `C:\Users\name\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` and open `profile.ps1`, you will find some code that can initialize conda environment, so every time you open project with powershell, the conda environment will also be activated, there're two solutions:

1.Comment the code in profile.ps1;

2.Choose cmd as your default Terminal in VS Code.

Comment: This setting is deprecated for me. Just got a popup in VScode leading me to this: [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/AB-Experiments) where it says that pythonpath is deprecated

Comment: Ok, I opted out of the experiment and "undeprecated" my pythonpath setting. Now the interpreter is set correctly when I start the project but the virtualenv is still the conda environment from my main system.

Comment: @3ng7n33r. I've update my answer, have a try.